# Memoization of recursive calls on separate lines

Tags: javascript, recursion, depth-first-search, fibonacci, memoization

I am attempting to solve [Leetcode problem 70](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/) by first trying to visualize the tree and then implement the solution. The tree is simple in that the left branch is a single step and the second branch is a double step.

For n = 3, the tree would be;

```
      /  \
     /    \
    1      2
   / \    /
  1   2  1
 /
1
```

Giving `1,1,1`, `1,2` and `2,1` for a total of `3`. I came up with a non-memoized solution which uses two recursive 'branch' calls

```js
var climbStairs = function(n) {
  let dfs = (combination) => {
    let steps = combination.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0)

    if (steps === n) {
      output.push(combination)
      return
    }

    if (steps > n) {
      return
    }

    dfs([...combination, 1])
    dfs([...combination, 2])
  }

  let output = []
  dfs([])
  return output.length
};
```

This works, but times out for larger numbers as expected. So I have two questions;

1. Is it possible to have a memoized version of my attempt above? (i.e. when the recursive branch calls are on separate lines)
2. All other solutions on the site use a variation of fibonacci; `dfs(step + 1) + dfs(step + 2)`. I don't quite understand why the two recursive calls should be added in this example problem. What is the 'give away' that adding the two recursive calls is the way to go rather than branching on different lines?

Comment: I don't understand the second question: your "branching on different lines" also involves two recursive calls, and they are quite the same as the fibonacci calls, except that you maintain an array for each path, while the other solutions only keep a sum and don't care about the array. It is the same thing really. Moreover, on Stack Overflow a question should be one question only or it will be voted as "too broad".

Comment: Even if you would add memoization, this solution will still be slow because of all the array iterations and copying. And keeping all those arrays (and each time taking their sum) to in the end only to *count* them, is a waste of resource and time.

Answer (score 0):

Memoization will not help your algorithm. This is because there is nothing to memoize: no two calls to `dfs` will have the same input (can you show why?).

I believe the main observation in this problem is that we don't need to store trajectories. To arrive at step `k`, we can either take one step from  `k - 1` or two steps from `k - 2`. Suppose there are `n` ways to arrive at `k - 1` and `m` ways to arrive at `k - 2`. Then to arrive at `k`, we must either

1. Choose a path to `k - 1` and take an additional step (`n` ways)
2. Choose a path to `k - 2` and take an additional step (`m` ways)

So there are `n + m` ways to arrive at `k`, or more generally, `steps(k) = steps(k - 1) + steps(k - 2)`. There is no need to store the actual path itself because we care only about the number of steps.